# Sharepoint exception "value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharedpreferences, sharepoint-2013

Here is the below code

```
string url="\\abc.org\|test1\\test2\\test3\\test4"
using (ClientContext CC= new CC(url))
{
}
```

getting this exception "**value does not fall within the expected range**"

Comment: did you try to escape backslashes? also why you are using backslashes insead normal slashes in something called `url` ?

Comment: I tried "//abc.org//test1//test2//test3//test4"  still getting the same exception.
I tied "\\abc.org\\test1\\test2\\test3\\test4" in browser and am able to access the url.
@Selvin

Comment: That URL does not look valid to me. I'd image it should look something like this: `ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://{site_url}");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the correct URL which you are using. Can you please put some different URL like "Https:test1.Microsoftsharepoint.com/sites/sitecollectionName.

If that will work, then modify your site URL.